# Stacking JavaScript arrays into object values in lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash, amcharts

I'm trying to stack JavaScript object array values in lodash, where each array value is to be mapped to a corresponding object in a resulting array of objects. Example:

```
olympicmedals = {
    '2008': [{'country': 'China', 'golds': 51}, {'country': 'USA', 'golds': 36}],
    '2012': [{'country': 'China', 'golds': 38}, {'country': 'USA', 'golds': 46}]
}
```

Desired result:

```
olympicmedals = [
    {'country': 'China', 'golds2008': 51, 'golds2012': 38},
    {'country': 'USA', 'golds2008': 36, 'golds2012': 46}
]
```

Fwiw, this is for charting in amCharts, such as seen [here](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/3d-stacked-column-chart/) (click 'View Demo Source' therein).

I assume the _.map() function is the way to go, just not quite sure how to proceed. Thanks!

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself". There are a ton of questions on SO regarding how to merge/map arrays.

Comment: After years of using SO for reference, this is my first question, after searching and researching and hitting a brick wall. Regardless, thanks for the advice! If this question has been asked before, or there are some key questions/references I missed, I'd appreciate a link to the original, and we can mark it as duplicate. Also, I have seen many, many questions that do not "Explain... any difficulties". Perhaps this should be phrased as a more specific question?

Comment: Just because a lot of people don't do the right thing, doesn't mean it's okay. Certainly you can take a few minutes to tells us what you've tried, so that we don't duplicate the effort?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `forEach()` loop, but you will also have to loop each object in arrays so you can add years to keys. It can also handle more object properties not just gold medals.

```js
var data = {
  '2008': [{
    'country': 'China',
    'golds': 51,
    silver: 10
  }, {
    'country': 'USA',
    'golds': 36
  }],
  '2012': [{
    'country': 'China',
    'golds': 38
  }, {
    'country': 'USA',
    'golds': 46,
    bronze: 10
  }]
}

var result = []
Object.keys(data).forEach(function(e) {
  var that = this;
  data[e].forEach(function(a) {
    if (!that[a.country]) {
      that[a.country] = {
        country: a.country
      }
      Object.keys(a).forEach(function(key) {
        if (key != 'country') that[a.country][e + key] = a[key]
      })
      result.push(that[a.country])
    } else {
      Object.keys(a).forEach(function(key) {
        if (key != 'country') that[a.country][e + key] = a[key]
      })
    }
  })
}, {})

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4))
```

Comment: Thanks, this certainly worked. I was hoping to use just one function for coding efficiency and readability, rather than nested for loops (that's really the whole point of lodash). However, I did end up using this approach, albeit still with _.forEach() instead of plain JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

A little late, but here's a map/reduce way to do this:

```js
o = {
    '2008': [{'country': 'China', 'golds': 51}, {'country': 'USA', 'golds': 36}],
    '2012': [{'country': 'China', 'golds': 38}, {'country': 'USA', 'golds': 46}]
}

const countries = o[Object.keys(o)[0]].map(e => e.country)

const result = countries.map(country => {
  return Object.keys(o).reduce((p, year) => {
    p[`golds${year}`] = o[year].find(e => e.country === country).golds
    return p
  }, {country})
})
console.log(result)
```

For this kind of transformation task, I find it convenient to get the column information first and store it in a variable (`countries`), based on which one can `filter` or `find` the associated data later. Probably there's also a way to do this without any local state, but I could imagine that it won't be very readable.